What might be causing this damage to siding?
Was away from cabin for a few weeks and came back to this. What might have done this - squirrel? birds?  Thanks for any help.
https://imgur.com/a/nkzmUtC?s=sms



We need some more information as to where the cabin is located. Could be porcupines.

Any other spoor around, like scat or hair or feathers or anything?

Thanks, all. The cabin is in the forest on the foothills of Mt. Hood in Oregon. We have a box elder bug infestation with a major source of entry near the damage. We were hypothesizing that it could be rodents trying to get at these bugs nested in the walls?  But wasn’t sure if squirrels ate box elders, or what else might be able to climb to that height. There is plenty of wildlife in the area, though all we ever see are rodents, birds (including large ground birds like turkeys), deer/elk. There is no hair or feathers in the area.

The high damage looks like black bear, to me. Standing up, reaching up, clawing at the siding, either to leave a mark just to leave a mark, or because interesting smells were coming from inside that a bear would like to taste. Sometimes they bite buildings, as well.
Lacks the gnawed or pecked look one expects from squirrels and woodpeckers, respectively. Looks ripped/clawed.

It's much too narrow and localized for bear. Rodents seems most likely to me.
